# Distribution of Active X Control .CAB file

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, com, activex

I am having difficulties trying to distribute an Active X control that I have created, the Active X control works fine if the component is registered manually (which is not good as it needs to be distributed to the user through IE). however when clicking the install button on the IE prompt, it simply doesn't install displaying no sign of any errors. My internet options are set to allow Active X controls to be installed.

The Active X control itself is a .Net dll which needs to be registered in the Component Services of the clients machine. I have followed the following walk through which seems to describe the same scenario that I face but it just doesn't seem to work.

I have even created the .exe to register the component that is describe in the example, set up the .inf file correctly but it just still refuses to install with no sign on any errors

Does anyone know is there is a log output for Active X installation that my help, or has anyone found a solution to a similar problem? I am using IE 8, 9, 10 compatibility mode

Example that I followed:-
http://www.mrrives.com/Technology/?p=767   I have also looked at MSDN website that surround this area